# Selecting strangely nested elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I can't seem to find a situation similar enough that I can figure out a solution. Without changing the html and adding classes and ids how can I select the `a` tag and the `pre` tag from the following code? I've included my attempts.

```css
div.info p.c6 span a {
  background-color: red;
}

p.c6 span pre {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="info">
  <h1 class="c4">
    <a name="h.6q469n2havqi"></a><span>Title</span>
  </h1>
  <p class="c6">
    <span>
     <pre>
     words
  </pre>
     <br>
     <a href="#h.c2v2rn37qt4d">Top of Page</a>
     <br>
    </span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Like `.info a` and `.info pre` ? you must want to do more than that right? like restrictions and stuff? Edit the question and put those constraints in

Comment: @Huangism I'm not sure what you mean by restrictions. And I honestly just want to know what I should do to just select the elements. If I can get them selected I can get the rest of my task done.

My main issue is that .info a selects the top a tag as well as the one inside the span.

Comment: @karthick I don't understand that notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the `p` element can only contain [*phrasing content*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content), and in this case it contains [*flow content*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content), the browser is closing the element and invalidating your selectors.

In short, the `pre` element is *flow content* and cannot be contained inside a `p` element. Therefore, the browser is overriding your HTML structure to maintain valid mark-up. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

The browser has essentially converted your `p` descendants into `p` siblings.

You need to restructure your HTML for your selectors to work.

If you can't change the HTML, [a sibling selector will work.](https://jsfiddle.net/rthjj6dr/)

Comment: Is that the only way? The html is generated by a program that I can't change so editing the html is very iffy.

Comment: @tsubi-rin find out how many places this thing is used to generate the html and see if you can just change the `p` to a `div` but selecting them is easy `.info h1 a` gives you the anchor in the header and `.info .c6 a` gives you the other one after you change the html. You could actually do `.info a` and `.info h1 a`, the more specific selector will override the more generic one